# Get specific value from JSON string in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this JSON string value as defined below. I want to get he value for "code" only.  I tried the solution in the internet but I am only getting a null value.  Any idea on this?

```
 JObject json = JObject.Parse(JSON string here);
 var jsonData = json.SelectToken("serviceMessage.code");    <-- THIS RETURNS NULL
```

The json:

```json
{
   "highestSeverity":"Error",
   "serviceMessage":[
      {
         "code":"3004",
         "severity":"Error",
         "reason":"Reason here."
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

Comment: Hint: `serviceMessage` is an _array_ . Therefore it doesn't have a "code" property, but the first item within the array does...

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can parse it to a model and get the value for *code*. E.g:

```
public class ServiceMessage
{
     public string code { get; set; }
     public string severity { get; set; }
     public string reason { get; set; }
}

public class Root{
   public string highestSeverity { get; set; }
   public List<ServiceMessage> serviceMessage { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
   public string MyFunction(string myJson){
       var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJson);
       //Then you can access the value in the object
       return data.serviceMessage.FirstOrDefault().code;
   }
}
```

Comment: No, because serviceMessage isn't an object, and also it isn't the outer item in the JSON

Comment: @ADyson "serviceMessage isn't an object, and also it isn't the outer item in the JSON" is a completely wrong statement. "serviceMessage"  is indeed a list of objects in a JSON notation ([link](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jsonp001.html) see reference), and is indeed an outer "item" since it's not enclosed by another object.

Comment: Sorry but no. `"serviceMessage" is indeed a list of objects`...yes. It's a **list**. It's not an **object**. In JSON, objects are surround by `{ }`, lists are surrounded by `[ ]`. and the way you parse them and access the items within them is different. And it _isn't_ the outer item because it's a named property inside the enclosing outer object. Even your hasty [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69269972/revisions) to add a "list" to the deserialisation doesn't help because you're still targeting only part of the object, and your method now tries to access the "code" property of a list.

Comment: For those reasons, your code doesn't work with the OP's JSON - which a moment's simple testing would reveal to you, even if, as it appears, you don't fully understand JSON syntax - demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gpnZCe . Even if we correct the "code" issue, it _still_ doesn't work because you're still trying to deserialise the whole object using a data structure which is aimed only at the list within it - demo 2: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oovm8I

Comment: FYI here's how it should _actually_ work using a strongly-typed deserialisation approach: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IgVFcl

Comment: True. Wanting to be straight to the point I ignored other parts of the JSON on purpose. I'm correcting my answer.

Comment: You can't ignore the rest of the JSON, it has to be parsed as a single item. Upvoted now you've edited to a usable version

Answer (score 3):

As `serviceMessage` is an array, assuming you want the first item you can simply use

```
var code = json["serviceMessage"][0]["code"];
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2WgkcF

Answer (score 2):

As it was indicated by [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) your `serviceMessage` in an array not an object. So, you have to treat it as a collection.

1. retrieve the collection
2. retrieve the first element from it
3. finally, you can get the `code` value

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(rawJson);
JArray messages = (JArray)json["serviceMessage"];
string code = messages.FirstOrDefault()?["code"]?.Value<string>()
```